# Can Apache routing be slow?

Tags: apache-2.2

I just wonder can Apache routing be slow?

My situation is this in. I define a ProxyPass, to different the incoming request ( for example, www.example.com ) to the relevant port ( for example, port 81), then at the httpd.conf for the example.com, I will have a few rewrite rules, some of them will direct the request to other domains. The reroutes will at most occurs 3 times. This means that the www.example.com will be reroute to port: 81, and if it matches a certain condition, then it might be rewroute to blog.example.com. And the blog.example.com will  then be reroute to port 83 of another pc.

Do you think that such a reroutes will eat up a lot of time?

Answer (score 1):

In general I would say that re-routes in the same network are fast. However, it is always a good idea to measure the delays yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ProxyPass it's not routing it's proxying. So in the worst case scenario you have the overhead of setting up two additional TCP/IP connections and moving content over these connections, i.e.

```
A says "GET HTTP/1.0..." to B.
B says "GET HTTP/1.0..." to C.
C says "GET HTTP/1.0..." to D.
D says "Answer..." to C.
C says "Answer..." to B.
B says "Answer..." to A.
```

If it's high volume you're looking for, proxying is probably not a good idea.

Can you not achieve the same thing with redirection (mod_rewrite by rewriting the requests?)

Comment: Hi, not sure rewriting will be possible because I have to direct the request call from one machine to another ( albelt in the same network)

Comment: AFAIK rewriting _is_ possible across absolute URLs (i.e. in between different HTTP servers).

Answer (score 0):

just a thought:

is it possible that your apache does reverse dns check for ip that sends the query? [ eg for logging ]? check if you have [HostnameLookups](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#hostnamelookups) directive in your config set to **Off**.